# Proof by induction $(2 n)! \geq n!^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction, factorial

I'm having trouble in solving this problem:

Prove by induction $(2 n)! \ge (n!)^2, \forall\ n\ge 0$

So far I came up with this:

$P(0): 2\ge1$ true

$P(n)\implies P(n+1): (2n+2)!\ge?[(n+1)!]^2$

$(2n+2)!=(2n)!\cdot(2n+2)\ge(n!)^2\cdot(2n+2)=$

$=(n!\cdot \frac{n+1}{n+1})^2\cdot(2n+2)=[(n+1)!\cdot \frac1{n+1}]^2\cdot2\cdot(n+1)=$

$=[(n+1)!]^2\cdot\frac{2\cdot(n+1)}{(n+1)^2}=[(n+1)!]^2\cdot\frac2{n+1}$

$$[(n+1)!]^2\cdot\frac2{n+1}\ge?[(n+1)!]^2$$

Now, this shouldn't be true anymore because if $n>1$ then $\frac2{n+1}<1$. Do you have any suggestion? I can't handle this kind of problems very well yet.

Comment: Check you line for $n=0$: $\quad P(0)=1\geq 1$, since $(2\cdot 0)!=0!=1$

Comment: $(2n+2)! \ne (2n)!(2n + 2)$.   $(2n+2)! = (2n+1)!(2n+2) = (2n)!(2n+1)(2n+2)$.  And $((n+1)!)^2 = (n!(n+1))^2 = (n!)^2(n+1)^2$.  So $(2n!)>(n!)^2$ and $(2n+1)(2n+2) > (n+1)^2$ so the result follows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, it should be $$P(1): 2\geq1.$$
Also, $P(0):1\geq1$ and by assumption of the induction we obtain:
$$(2n+2)!=(2n)!(2n+2)(2n+1)>(n!)^2(n+1)^2=((n+1)!)^2.$$

Comment: Thanks, yes I mistyped, it should be $P(0): 1\ge1$. However, I didn't understand how you obtained $(n+1)^2$ after >.

Comment: @Mazelpot   Because $(n!)^2(n+1)^2=(n!(n+1))^2=((n+1)!)^2.$

Comment: No I mean from $(2n+2)(2n+1)$ to $(n+1)^2$, did you drop the 2 because it was unnecessary?

Comment: @Mazelpot Because $2n+2>n+1$ and $2n+1>n+1$, which gives $(2n+2)(2n+1)>(n+1)(n+1)=(n+1)^2.$

Comment: Ok, that's quite reasonable. Thank you!

Comment: @Mazelpo  You are welcome!